# Making listview unscrollable or making listview expand vertically in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have 4 listview inside one scrollview. I know that scrollview is not required to make listview scrollable. But my problem is that I have too much content in one activity so have to make the whole layout scrollable else I'll miss out on contents. Till the contents fit in the screen the listviews are scrollable even inside scrollview (Figure 1). The moment the whole layout doesn't fit inside the display i.e when the scrollbar appears, the listviews are unscrollable (Figure 2).

[image: The original layout]

[image: After adding items]

The textviews below the autocomplete textview(ACTV) are hidden. Only when item is clicked in ACTV does the textview made visible.
Somehow I want to make the listview scrollable always or expand the display of listview as I add more and more items.

activity_centre.xml (This has the scrollview)

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_centre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nlss.custom_diet.Centre">


<TextView
    android:text="Breakfast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/bf"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bfac"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bf"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/bftvdisp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bfac"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/breakfastAddBT"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/bfcal" />

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bfListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bftvdisp">
</ListView>

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lnListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lntvdisp">
</ListView>

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dnListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dntvdisp">
</ListView>

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/snListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sntvdisp">
</ListView>


<TextView
    android:text="Lunch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bfListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/ln" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/bfac"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bf"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Select food" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/lnac"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bfac"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ln"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/breakfastAddBT"
    android:hint="Select food" />

<TextView
    android:text="Dinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/dn" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/dnac"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lnac"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lnac"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dn"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Select food" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dnac"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/dntvdisp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dnac"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dinnerAddBT"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/dncal" />

<TextView
    android:text="Snacks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dnListView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/sn" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/lntvdisp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnac"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bf"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/lncal"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LunchAddBT"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnac"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:hint="Select food"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/snac"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dnac"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dnac" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/snac"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/sntvdisp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/snac"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/snacksAddBT"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/sncal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/snacksAddBT"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dinnerAddBT"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/snac"
    android:text="Add"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/LunchAddBT"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/breakfastAddBT"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lnac"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dinnerAddBT"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LunchAddBT"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dnac"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/breakfastAddBT"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bfac"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bfac"
    android:text="Add" />
```

scrollview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NestedScroll Containers.You can enable it for a child scroll view by adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" in XML declaration or by explicitly calling setNestedScrollingEnabled(true). This method will only work for devices running API 21 and above.

For older and android version before API 20, you can use  classes from the Support library. First you have to replace you ScrollView with [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). The latter implements both NestedScrollingParent and NestedScrollingChild so it can be used as a parent or a child scroll container.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following snippet

```
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && scrollbarsVisible) {
                    return true;  // this will disable the scrolling in listview
                } 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: But by disabling the scrolling, will the whole listview be displayed?

Comment: No.. At any time You have one option, either scroll the listView or scroll the scrollView

Comment: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" does help to scroll both listview as well as the layout at any give time